# How are windows matched when calling MPI_Win_create

Tags: c++, c, mpi

Say, this piece of code :

```
int n; 
double pi; 

if (myid == 0) { 
    MPI_Win_create(&n, sizeof(int), 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, 
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nwin); 
    MPI_Win_create(&pi, sizeof(double), 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, 
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, &piwin);  
} 
else { 
    MPI_Win_create(MPI_BOTTOM, 0, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, 
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nwin); 
    MPI_Win_create(MPI_BOTTOM, 0, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, 
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, &piwin); 
}
```

from http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/usingmpi2/examples/starting/cpi-rma_c.htm

My question is how are the windows matched ?

My though is that it's the call order that matters, but my teacher suggested it could be the variable name (with some compiler intelligent trick).

I could try this code on OpenMPI, but would it be the specification behavior ?

So, how is it in the specifications ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher is unfortunately wrong. `MPI_Win_create` is collective over the ranks in the specified communicator and as such the order matters. Should you switch the order of the calls in the `else` block, then the handle to the first window created would be stored in `nwin` at rank 0 and in `piwin` at all other ranks. The same applies in reverse to the second window.

Virtually all MPI implementations are regular object code libraries and no compiler assistance whatsoever outside from emitting function calls is needed. Besides, MPI allows for jobs consisting of instances of several different executables (MPMD mode). How is the compiler then going to know the name of the variables in the other executables, when those could even be compiled with an entirely different compiler or written in different programming languages?